# Is there any way to get the request made, instead of the response?

Tags: javascript, google-geolocation

In the geolocator API, the function `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` sends a POST request to the Google geolocator API, with the following json body:

```json
{
  "wifiAccessPoints":[
    //insert the listening access points here
  ]
}
```

What I want is not the response from the API, but instead this JSON in the request it made. Is there any way to save this request in a variable? Or will I have to intercept it with a proxy?

Comment: You probably need a proxy. This is an implementation detail, there's no reason why it would be exposed through an API.

Comment: I think this is a classic XY problem - the library Google provides should abstract any & all need for you to inspect *anything* about the request. What is it *actually* you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @esqew I need to save the mac addresses and signal strengths of every device near me programmatically in a file. It doesn't necessarily needs to be in javascript, but has to run on windows.